# Query for Related Attachments works in query editor but not Apex

Tags: apex, soql, files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to make a simple APEX Class that returns a records related attachments.
When I do the following SOQL query in the Query Editor I get the 3 expected results:

```
SELECT Id
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'a36Ec00000001s9IAA'`
```

However, when I do the same query in my apex class, nothing is returned in the list.  I have been stuck on this for a while and any help would be appreciated.  The recordId value is displaying in the debug as it should.  Here is my entire Apex class so far:

```
global class GetRelatedAttachments {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Related Attachments')
    global static List<ContentDocumentLink> getRelatedAttachments(List<FlowInputs> requests){
        
        String recordId = requests[0].recordId;
        
        List<ContentDocumentLink> IdList = [
            SELECT ContentDocumentId
            FROM ContentDocumentLink
            WHERE LinkedEntityId =: recordId
        ];
        
        System.debug('recordId: '+ recordId);
        System.debug('List: '+ IdList);
        return IdList;
    }
    
    global class FlowInputs{
       
        @InvocableVariable
        global Id recordId;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: is it the same running user (query editor vs invocable apex)?  do you observe the invocable error during flow debugging or via apex testmethods?

Comment: @cropredy I believe it is the same running user.  When I run the flow debugger and get to the apex class I get the error: "Error Occurred: The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your problem is that you need to return a List of lists

```
global static List<List<ContentDocumentLink>> getRelatedAttachments(List<FlowInputs> requests){

    ...
    return new List<List<ContentDocumentLink>> {idList};
}
```

Apex Actions are bulkified by Flow. If *n* Flow Interviews for a transaction reach an apex action, their input args are collected into a list that the invocable processes in bulk and the return from the invocable must be a list of the same size *and same order* as the incoming list.

This is true even in Screen Flows which typically pass to an invocable apex an input argument collection of size = 1 and should return, if they return at all, a list of size 1.

***Notes***

- I'd seriously suggest you rename the variable `idList` to be `contentDocumentLinks` as that is what the SOQL fetches
- I'd also suggest renaming the class `FlowInputs` to `FlowInput` or better, `Request`. Classnames should not be plural in almost all situations.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return a `List<Id>` instead of a `List<ContentDocumentLink>` for an invocable method.
You can also wrap the return type in a class with an invocable variable. Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

Comment: The documentation you point do says that a list of an SObject type is allowed as a return type, so I don't think this is the issue.